# getBinding is not working after the page loads

Tags: sapui5

I'm getting error with getBindin function.I have to filter data as soon as the page loads.I have made a split app where in master page after user clicks on the name of the user all the details are displayed in the detailsPage.This code is for the detailsPage.I'm getting the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBinding' of undefined

```
return Controller.extend("com.Second.SecondProject.controller.SecondPage", {
    onInit: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("DetailsPage").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    },
    _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
        var selectedArguments = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
        var selectedRecord = selectedArguments.value;
        console.log(selectedRecord);
        var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("UserList");

        var oBinding = oList.getBinding("users");
        console.log(oBinding);
        var aFilter = [];
        aFilter.push(new Filter("name", FilterOperator.Contains, selectedRecord));
        oBinding.filter(aFilter);
        // var obj = {
        //  "Objects": selectedRecord
        // };
        // var navigationobjModel = new JSONModel();
        // navigationobjModel.setData(obj);
        // this.getView().setModel(navigationobjModel, "users");
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the error message it seems that instead of having a problem in the data binding, you are failing to get the list using `sap.ui.getCore().byId`.

Assuming you have a XML view or created ids using `createId` method, you should use methods `this.byId()` or `this.getView().byId()` to get the list.

Tip: Usually when you have an error like `Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined` usually the error is in the variable you use before XXX.

As the `oList` variable is undefined, you are getting this error.